# AutoCompleteTextView: Dismiss dropdown and close activity if soft keyboard was hidden?

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, onbackpressed

I have a custom AutoCompleteTextView and on the first back press I want to hide the soft keyboard. On the next back press I want to go back to the previous activity.
So broke it down as below:

1. If device's back is pressed then hide the soft keyboard instead of
   dismissing the AutoCompleteTextView or going back to previous
   activity.
2. If device's back is pressed and keyboard is already hidden, then
   instantly go back to the previous activity.

For part 1, I wrote this inside my custom widget for AutoCompleteTextView:

```
@Override
  public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
      InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isPopupShowing()) {
          if(inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)){
              return true;
          }
      }
      return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
  }
```

And this worked fine.
For part2, I modified my code and added a listener in my custom AutoCompleteTextView like this:

```
@Override
  public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event) {
      InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && isPopupShowing()) {
        if(inputManager.isAcceptingText()){
          if(inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)){
            return true;
          }
        } else {
          callback.onSecondClick();
        }
      }
      return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
  }
  public void setCallback(MyAutoCompleteTextViewInterface callback){
      this.callback = callback;
  }
  public interface MyAutoCompleteTextViewInterface{
      void onSecondClick();
  }
```

And in my activity, I did:

```
@Override
    public void onSecondClick() {
        finish();
    }
```

The problem is that on first back press it does hide the soft keyboard, but on next back press it just dismisses the dropdown. Then I need to press back for the third time in order to get to the previous activity.

I know there are problems with my approach, but unable to figure it out.

Comment: override the `onBackPressed()` method of the activity

Comment: @Ashish Ranjan, a complete answer would help. I tried the same code in onBackPressed() with required changes, but it didn't help.